# How to remove Payments from my app

Tags: facebook, facebook-credits, credits

is there a way to remove the "Payments" from my app?
I didn't use it in the past, I don't want to use it in the future and also don't want to recieve the Credits emails every day.

Regards, Code.Working

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions below to remove your payment information from your Facebook account. Please note that if you have made any payments on friends’ or family members accounts, your payment information will be stored on their account unless it is removed manually.

To remove your payment information from Facebook:

- Log into the account
- Go to "Account Settings" in the "Account" drop-down menu on the top right of your home page
- Click "Payments"
- Next to Payment Methods, click "Manage"

You can then remove your credit card, PayPal account or mobile phone number.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to remove Payments from my account but from my app. (I am a developer...)